# How to display checkbox value and text in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, wpf-controls

I need to display value and text contained in the particular `CheckBox` which is checked on its checked event in WPF. How to do that?

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(........need help here......);
}
```

Comment: UI is not data. you should not care about what's "contained" in the CheckBox. Create a proper ViewModel to hold your data and show that instead.

Comment: @HighCore - Can you explain a bit more...

Comment: Checkboxes do not have `Value` and `Text` properties, however they do have a `Content` property. Is that what you are looking for? `((CheckBox)sender).Content).ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your expectations. You want to retrieve the value "checked" - "unchecked" from the checkBox?

So can you try this?

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Get the boolean current value [true or false]
     bool valueSelectedToBool = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;

     //Get the string current value ["true" or "false"]
     string valueSelectedToString = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked.ToString();

     MessageBox.Show(valueSelectedToString );
}
```

Comment: Getting error with your code: Error 13 The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: sorry do you can try with '.IsChecked' ? I have edited my answer

Comment: I think he wants the text of the checkbox and not the IsChecked.ToString(); He wants the (sender as CheckBox).Content

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

I don't know if you want the uncheck action to trigger the event but I put it.

In XAML :

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked_1" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
```

In C# :

```
  private void CheckBox_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox check = sender as CheckBox;
            MessageBox.Show(check.IsChecked.Value.ToString());
        }
```

Just tested it, it works.
I hope it is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with WPF.
I used these lines of code. In my case it works properly.

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool Chked = Convert.ToBoolean((sender as CheckBox).IsChecked);
    string ChkBoxContent = (sender as CheckBox).Content.ToString();
    TxtHabitsHx.AppendText(ChkBoxContent);
}
```